# python Shift + enter not working in VScode with jupyter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I have a new install of VS Code Version 1.50.1 with the python extension that now added the Jupyter extension. The Jupyter extension build number is 2020.12.411183115 When I press shift enter on the default it adds a new line below. You can see in the video that shift + enter should work to run the line. At this point the only way I can run code in the interactive window is with ctrl + shift + p and select run selected cell.

**Edit after working with Danny Varod and the comments below:**
Changing the keyboard shortcut to ctrl + enter and nothing happens (it does not add a new line below). I press ctrl + shift + p and I see that the correct shortcut is crtl + enter but it will not trigger the action

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my keyboard shortcuts before the change.

[image]

Changing my keyboard shortcuts to match the comment below. Now when I press ctrl + enter nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use the following shortcut key settings:

```json
{
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "jupyter.execSelectionInteractive",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

This shortcut key is set with the use conditions, and it can be used only when it is confirmed (including the control panel is opened). Therefore, we can remove the use conditions for this shortcut key.

[image]

Comment: This is what mine was set to on default. After changing to match the above it works.   

"editorTextFocus && jupyter.ownsSelection && !findInputFocussed && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"

Answer (score 20):

In `settings.json` under `.vscode` add the following line:

```
"jupyter.interactiveWindow.textEditor.executeSelection": true
```

Then `Shift+Enter` should work.

Comment: This answer worked better for me, as the accepted answer messed up with the shortcut when used the Interactive pane.

Comment: It does't work now......

Comment: I found that this answer worked when: using it **alone** in `settings.json` _and_ **removing** any custom keybindings in `keybindings.json`, such as: `"key": "shift+enter", "command": "jupyter.execSelectionInteractive", "when": "editorTextFocus"`. The result is that `Shift + Enter` when the text editor is focused runs code in an interactive python window, and then `Shift + Enter` also runs code in the **same** interactive window when entered in the code input box of that interactive window.

Comment: `"jupyter.interactiveWindow.textEditor.executeSelection": true` per warning: `This setting has been deprecated in favor of jupyter.interactiveWindow.textEditor.executeSelection.`

Answer (score 3):

`Shift+Enter` also inserted a new line for me, unmapping this prevented this.

I changed to mappings to:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

These mappings work for me, however, in Jupyter notebooks (`.ipynb`) the `Ctrl+Enter` and `Shift+Enter` are swapped vs. what I defined .

Also, I am using the following Python extensions:

- "MagicPython" `magicstack.magicpython`
- "Jupyter" `ms-toolsai.jupyter`

**Both installed by**:

- "Python Extension Pack" `donjayamanne.python-extension-pack`

When I open `.ipynb` files they open as Jupyter notebooks.
When I open `.py` files I can either use Jupyter or MagicPython (and nether say Python).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I updated my text above after making these changes. No luck

Comment: @Jeffkrop I just noticed - you're in a `.py` file, not a Jupyter notebook `.ipynb`, so you're looking at the wrong settings.

Comment: this has worked in a past for a .py file. Did this change in the last week?

Comment: @Jeffkrop Not that I know of. Maybe an extension update changed something or maybe you configured the tab to use a different Python interpreter (MagicPython) than in the past (Juptyer).

Comment: Ok after installing MagicPython I now see that in the lower right. But still when I press shift enter it adds a new line. If I press ctrl + shift + p I can select run line with interactive window and shows the shortcut as shit + enter.

Comment: @Jeffkrop what are your mapped MagicPython shortcuts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225800/discussion-between-jeffkrop-and-danny-varod).

Comment: I have done everything the same except I use crtl + enter for jupyter run selection/line in interactive window. It still with not trigger with the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was solved by removing the Command `Insert Line Bellow` which was supposedly conflicting with my `shift + enter` hotkey in notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a new setting to toggle this behavior. I just had to add this line to the settings file:

## Configure for Workspace

```json
// file: .vscode/settings.json
{
  "jupyter.interactiveWindow.textEditor.executeSelection": true
}
```

## Set as default for user

1. Open command palette and selected "Preferences: Open User Settings"
   [image]
2. Type "Jupyter execute selection"
   [image]
3. Ensure the checkbox is checked

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was with extensions; I installed `Python` and `Jupyter` from the `Extension` menu on the left panel, then it worked.

**Note:** I had already added the following lines to ‍‍‍‍`setting.json`:

```
"jupyter.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to change is **Notebook: Execute cell**:

[image]